# Sorting a Tuple By Its Second Index

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, tuples

I am trying to sort a multi-tuple with double indexes in Python. I want to sort it by it's second index. The tuple output, which is the output of "print(max_values)", looks like:

```
(array([[4.15498641]]), 1)
(array([[2.31940546]]), 4)
(array([[0.96185454]]), 8)
(array([[1.29915758]]), 11)
(array([[1.66805024]]), 5)
(array([[1.25312376]]), 13)
(array([[1.81367542]]), 7)
(array([[3.16895748]]), 14)
(array([[3.74632224]]), 0)
(array([[4.87073571]]), 10)
(array([[1.8860763]]), 12)
(array([[1.25379793]]), 6)
(array([[0.60556452]]), 15)
(array([[3.09510515]]), 3)
(array([[2.7700944]]), 9)
(array([[2.65579492]]), 2)
```

What I want to do exactly is, this is to put these tuples in order according to the second index of the tuples you see.

For example, in the output I added, the second index of the first tuple is 1, while the second index of the second tuple is 4. What I want to do is set the second index equal to 2.

I am also adding the full code, "takeSecond" function didn't work.

```
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed(2)
np.random.seed(2)

x_train = [(np.random.randn(1,3),0), (np.random.randn(1,3),1), (np.random.randn(1,3),2) , (np.random.randn(1,3),3),
           (np.random.randn(1,3),4), (np.random.randn(1,3),5), (np.random.randn(1,3),6) , (np.random.randn(1,3),7),
           (np.random.randn(1,3),8), (np.random.randn(1,3),9), (np.random.randn(1,3),10), (np.random.randn(1,3),11),
           (np.random.randn(1,3),12),(np.random.randn(1,3),13),(np.random.randn(1,3),14), (np.random.randn(1,3),15)]

neurons = [(np.random.randn(3,1),0), (np.random.randn(3,1),1), (np.random.randn(3,1),2),
           (np.random.randn(3,1),3), (np.random.randn(3,1),4), (np.random.randn(3,1),5),
           (np.random.randn(3,1),6), (np.random.randn(3,1),7), (np.random.randn(3,1),8)]

def takeSecond(elem):
    return elem[1]


#%%

random.shuffle(x_train)

for i in range (len(x_train)):
        results = []
        winning_neurons = []
        for j in range (len(neurons)):
            result = np.dot(x_train[i][0],neurons[j][0])
            results.append((result,x_train[i][1]))                
        #results.sort(key=takeSecond)
        #print(results)   
        max_values = max(results)
        print(max_values)
        max_index = results.index(max_values)
        winning_neurons.append(max_index)
        #print(winning_neurons)
```

Other tuple sorting functions on the internet, didn't work and gave errors like "index error" or "sort() function not working for tuples".

Could you help me to sort this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you include the exact error that you get when the `results.sort` call is not commented?

Comment: The nature of that "tuple output" is unclear.  Is that successive prints?  From where in the code?  Are you trying to sort a list of such tuples?  To get the best answers, make the example and code as simple and reproducible, and show any errors in full.

Comment: @shriakhilc hello, the "result.sort" call that I wrote in the code and commented does not give an error, but it does not work as I want. Does not sort the tuples. I added new explanations to my question. You can have a look.

Comment: @hpaulj hello, I added new explanations. You can have a look. Tuple output is the output of "max_values". But I couldn't sort by the second index.

Comment: @Manlai hello,  I don't get an error statement by the compiler, but as I said, tuples are not sorted by their second index.

Comment: @Manlai yes, exactly. Sorting them and adding a list, if it’s possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and show a *complete* example. We should have hard-coded, complete input (we should not have to guess what you mean by "multi-tuple with double indexes", and we should not have to create one); we should see the exact, complete desired output for that input; and we should see the exact, complete actual output.

Comment: On the other hand, do not show us irrelevant setup code. We don't care how `results` is computed - we care about exactly what it is, *immediately before* the attempt to do anything with it. We also care about why you are trying to use `max` and `sort`, what results you expect from each, and whether you really intend to use both, in what order, etc.

Comment: If you have indexing errors in @Manlai answer, then your `results` is not the list of 2 element tuples that your question implies.  You need to provide clearer information about the object  that you are trying to sort.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually use `takeSecond` as a `key` function to get the behavior you want. `results.sort(key=takeSecond)` does sort the list, but that order has no effect on the call to `max()`, and you make no use of the sorted `results` list anywhere else.

By default, the `max` method takes the first item in a tuple for comparison, hence you need to pass a `key` here too:

```py
max_values = max(results, key=takeSecond)
```

In your sample data, this would return `(array([[0.60556452]]), 15)`.

If you just need the max tuple based on this criteria, using `max()` is better than sorting the entire `results` list. If you need to have sorted `results` anyway, then there is no need to use `max()`, the maximum tuple will be at `results[-1]`, the last item since `results.sort(key=takeSecond)` will be sorted in ascending order.